# Credits for the Pub/private key pair generation design in IOTA

Tags: signing, winternitz

I have understood that IOTA uses a constant Seed and a variable index to generate Winternitz private and keys, to sign transactions.

PK^-1 = Hash (Seed + index)

So we can have practically endless PK pairs. This is something beyond the Lamport, Winternitz, Merkle, and some further OT-Signature schemes like CMSS, XMSS, and so on.
SO:
I have reviewed a few papers and some pages on the internet, and still do not know ***who came up with this*** first? 
IOTA Foundation? Winternitz? Merkle? I am trying to cite.

Comment: There is one Error in your assumptions. You cannot have endless pk pairs. To understand why, you have to understand what the index does. The index itself changes your seed by counting up in Trytes. So if my Seed is AAAAA... and my index is 1, this will change the seed to BAAAAA.... So as you see, the pk pairs are limited to 27^81.